# what is the difference between viewpager and recyclerview?

Tags: android

what is the difference between viewpager and recyclerview?

I would like to create the effect similar to Instagram Explore Tab. But both looks similar for me to use, may I ask which one is better to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewpager and Recyclerview are very different for the purpose they have been designed.

**ViewPager:**

> Layout manager that allows the user to flip left and right through
>   pages of data.

**RecyclerView:**

> A flexible view for providing a limited window into a large data set.

If your data is suitable for both of them, go with this:

https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager

:)